# Sliding questions using PHP and JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, horizontal-scrolling

I have a simple website, I want it to ask 10 questions and save the answers to a database.

I would like it to be a little interactive and only display one question at a time.  then when the user answers that question, the div slides to the left and displays the next question until all questions have been asked and the page then submits the answers to a database.  The answers would be saved under the users IP address.

So this is how I envision it working:

> Q1: What is your name?

User enters details (eg Tony) and then presses next, the database populates as follows:

```
UserID: 192.168.0.1 QuestionID: 1 Answer: Tony
```

Then the user is shown question 2.

> What is your favourite colour?
> User answers the question and selects next.  Database populates:

```
UserID: 192.168.0.1 QuestionID: 2 Answer: Blue
```

Eventually getting to the final question and clicking submit.

I can do the submit etc, but I am struggling to find a way to implement a multiple div layout that looks smooth and elegant.

Any ideas?

```
<div><h1>Question 1: What is your name?</h1></div>
<div><input type="text" name="yourName" class="inputBox" value="" required /></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A method that uses jquery and display none class:

JS

```
function next(this_q, next_q) {
     // SAVE DATA TO DB VIA AJAX ETC...
     $("#q"+this_q).toggleClass("d-none");
     $("#q"+next_q).toggleClass("d-none");
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="q1">
     This is question 1?
     <input ... >
     <button onclick="next(1,2);" ... >
</div>
<div id="q2" class="d-none">
     This is question 2?
     <input ... >
     <button onclick="next(2,3);" ... >
</div>
<div id="q3" class="d-none">
     This is question 3?
     <input ... >
     <button onclick="next(3,4);" ... >
</div>
more divs ...
```

Obviously style etc is missing but I'd do it kinda like this.

When the next button is clicked:

saves the answer -> hides the answer -> shows the next one

Comment: + you could add something like a progressbar

Comment: Thank you so much for the code, I don't know what I am doing wrong but it doesn't work for me.

I added the function to the head and the code in the relevant div.

Comment: @TonySavage 1) did you add the jquery library? 2) do they have the same id as in the example code? 3) did you call the function onclick?

Comment: ><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
><script>function next(this_q, next_q) {
>$("#q"+this_q).toggleClass("d-none");
>$("#q"+next_q).toggleClass("d-none");
>}</script>

Comment: Comments arent displaying my code correctly lol sorry.  1) I added the jquery library before the script. 2) I haven't changed the ID from the sample.  3) I thought the function was called next?  I just copied and pasted it